# How to exectute "Insert into select * " query with extra columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In bigquery, i have created two tables table1(id,name) and table2(id,name,address,time). table1 has 10 rows in it while table2 is empty.

I want to insert all data from table1 into table2 plus values for address ("abc" for all rows) and time (now()) columns.

Whats is the perfect way to write `insert into table2 select * from table1, "abc", now()` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
insert into table2 
select *, "abc", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
from table1
```